# Return a variable by a function and store it a new variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create two functions: one should "produce" a number and the other should perform a function with as parameter this number.

I got the following code

```
sub get_number()
  Dim x as Integer
  x = 3
  return x
end sub
```

But I cant get this to return a numeric value because it throws a compile error. Any thoughts on how I can get this function to return a x value and store it in a new variable (fe y()

Comment: When facing an *error* (compile-time, exception etc.), please, provide the *text* of the message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a function, not a Sub, and assign the return value to the name of the function:

```
Function get_number()
  Dim x as Integer
  x = 3
  get_number = x
end Function
```

then use:

```
y = get_number
```

in your other code.

Answer (score 1):

`Sub` can't return a value; use a `Function`:

```
Function get_number()
    Dim x as Integer
    x = 3
    get_number = x
End Function

myNumber = get_number()
MsgBox myNumber ' will return the 3
```

Or you can stick with the `Sub` and handle the return value with a parameter (which you'll have to define in the calling function or earlier)

```
Sub get_number(byRef myNumber) ' accepts myNumber as a parameter and returns its value
  Dim x as Integer
  x = 3
  myNumber = x
End Sub
```